# IOS w/ SpriteKit How to edit a pre-existing label?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I made a label in my LaunchScreen.sks file, named it touchLabel, and I can't seem to find a method for accessing it anywhere.

So how do I set a "let" equal to the label that I created in my .sks file, I know how to create one I just can't figure out how to access one I already created.

I figured the code would be something along the lines of:

```
let touchLabel = SKLabelNode(named: "touchLabel")
```

but "named:" is not an available overload for that function.

I remembered to set the name of the label in the .sks file to touchLabel and also remembered to set the parent to LaunchScreen.swift

Also Im really sorry if this is super obvious I am new to swift and I've looked for a solution for at least an hour, but I have only found pages on how to create labels from the .swift file. Not how to access labels that have already been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `childNode(withName:)` to find elements in the `sks` file.

```
var touchLabel: SKLabelNode!

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    guard let touchLabel = childNode(withName: "touchLabel") as? SKLabelNode else {
        fatalError("touchLabel node not loaded")
    }

    self.touchLabel = touchLabel
}
```